# The `ended` event fires twice per played node after some time

Tags: javascript, chromium, web-audio-api

The `ended` event fires twice (or more) per single `AudioScheduledSourceNode` instance for me in Chrome, Edge and Opera on Windows. Firefox seem to fire the mentioned event once per node.

```js
var buffersPlaying = 0;

function bufferEnded() {
    // This function is called twice (or more?) per one source node
    buffersPlaying -= 1;  
}

function play(output, buffer) {
    const source = context.createBufferSource();
    source.buffer = buffer;
    source.connect(output);
    source.start(context.currentTime);
    source.addEventListener('ended', bufferEnded);
    buffersPlaying += 1;
}
```

At first the `ended` event is fired only once per node, but **after few minutes and thousands of played sounds**, this event starts to fire twice for some played buffers.

Is is normal that the event fires twice, or is it a browser bug?

Comment: No it's not normal.

Comment: An example that shows this and a bug filed at https://crbug.com/new would be very helpful.  If there's no bug filed, no one can work on a fix.